# Reduce the width of Bootstrap navbar item containing image

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

I was designing a bootstrap navbar with a YouTube logo. Instead of aligning to right it is awkwardly placed in center. It seems the width of anchor is more than the size of image as result the image is pushed to right. How can I move it to right.

```css
.navbar-brand{
  font-family: Lilita One;
}

.navbar-top{
  padding: 0 0;
}

.navbar{
  padding: 0 5% 0 2%;
}

.yt-img{
  width: 6%;
  position: relative;
}

.yt-img-a{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Education Side</title>
  <!-- Tab Icon -->
  <link rel="icon" href="images\Icon.ico">
  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lilita+One&family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid navbar-top">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Education<br>Side</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link yt-img-a" href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img class="yt-img" src="images\youtube.png" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Counselling</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Recruitment</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrlcV.png)

Comment: Do you want your image on left side.  With the logo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the image width to `6%`, use a px value such as `30px`.

```
.yt-img{
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/8yPSl6ClBa)

Comment: Again what's the image size?

Comment: 512 height and width

Answer (score 0):

The `ms-auto` class makes your `ul` to be placed on the right side.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto"> // ms-auto removed
```

**Codepen Link:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/JjRMxQw

Have fixed that and also added `flex-grow:1` where ever needed  :)

**Full Code:**

```css
.navbar-brand{
  font-family: Lilita One;
}

.navbar-top{
  padding: 0 0;
}

.navbar{
  padding: 0 5% 0 2%;
}

.yt-img{
  width: 6%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Education Side</title>
  <!-- Tab Icon -->
  <link rel="icon" href="images\Icon.ico">
  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lilita+One&family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid navbar-top">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Education<br>Side</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
            <li class="nav-item flex-grow-1">
              <a class="nav-link yt-img-a" href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img class="yt-img" src="images\youtube.png" alt="Image Here"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Counselling</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Recruitment</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```